# Tableau Workbooks Error

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, tableau-api

I have 3 Tableau workbooks and 1 work book is a fact table and rest two are tables related to the previous one I need to fetch them into one workbook and make charts using all three tables data. I am unable to fetch all three workbooks into single workbook to work with all 3 of them.

I have .tab files with one fact table and 2 dimension tables in .tab files and I need to use all three files and make charts using that data

Comment: Do you mean Tableau workbooks or database tables? To join multiple tables, use the multiple tables choices in the data connection pane.

Comment: I have tables saved as Tableau Workbooks

Comment: That doesn't really make sense from Tableau's terminology. A Tableau workbook (.twb file) contains one or more worksheets (tabs) and also contains one or more data connections (listed in the top of the data pane on the left of a worksheet). Each worksheet references a single primary data connection which is shown by being checked. Each data connection references some external data source which can be a database or file. A data connection can join multiple tables to present a single view to Tableau. You can also blend secondary data sources with the primary on a worksheet.

Comment: Not trying to be difficult, but I recommend editing your question to be more clear about the specifics of your problem. What do your tables look like? Where is the data stored? Workbooks do not store data, just instructions about how to visualize data from external data sources.

Comment: Still a confusing question. Try describing your data, leaving tableau out of it. Are your three tables in a database? A .xlsx file? There .cvs files? What are the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Based on the Tableau Desktop documentation, you could](http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/current/pro/online/en-us/help.htm#copy_b_wkbks.html)

- Copy and paste selected sheets to another workbook.
- Import a saved workbook into your current workbook.
- Export selected sheets to a new workbook.

[If you've got an older version of Tableau, such as 8.0, then try using bookmarks](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/bookmark-copy-sheet?lang=en-us)